# CoreLocation - what do the latitude and longitude numbers actually represent

Tags: latitude-longitude, distance

I have :

+37.785834 (lat)
-122.406417 (long)

The LAT positive means North of the equator
The LONG negative means to the West of 0

So far so good.

But what does the number represent exactly ? For example suppose I added 0.000001 to the LAT what would this actually represent ? That I have moved in some Northerly direction by 1 metre, for example or....

If I understand what these numbers actually represent then I can use them intelligently.

Comment: Not sure if this belongs on stackoverflow.com. Have you tried searching for the answer to your question on www.gooogle.com or www.yahoo.com or www.bing.com? I did and found the answer within seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longitude and latitude are measured in *degrees*. The latitude ranges from -90° (south pole) to +90° (north pole). The longitude ranges from -180° to +180°.